# ¿Hay alguna manera de obtener si un elemento está junto a otro (anexo) en jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funciones

Necesitaría implementar una función que me dijera por ejemplo si dos elementos están anexos. Por ejemplo, estoy haciendo un rompecabezas deslizante (slide puzzle) con una imagen cortada en 15 trozos y cada trozo en una celda de una tabla de 4x4. La última celda es un cuadrado negro. Necesito que al hacer clic en un `<td>` se intercambie la posición con el `<td>`negro, pero sólo si está anexo al lado de éste. Sino, no es válido el movimiento.

Comment: Añade a cada "pieza" un par de [atributos personalizados](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos), `data-x` y `data-y`, así será fácil calcular cuales son sus contiguos:  (x-1,y) (x+1,y) (x,y-1) y (x,y+1)

Comment: Puedes colocar el HTML de la tabla. Eso ayudaría a plantear el selector.